# Django filebrowser tinymce - Can't upload images

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

I have installed tinymce, django-filebrowser and grappelli.

Everything works nice except that I can't upload files to my local dev server.
When I click on Insert/Edit image icon in Tinymce editor and then on Browse button I get the page where I can see a list of my already uploaded images through django's image upload method in media/images/ folder.

However when I click the Upload button a get the Upload page but no possibilities for selecting and uploading images/files.

Here is the screenshot of that window.

https://gyazo.com/175028ba6630d94f1ddd7148697775ab

When I inspect the window there is an error message in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &                        127.0.0.1/:97
```

Comment: looks like errors in your javascript files. Click on error message in console and you will see where is problem

Comment: @AlmasK89 I wasn't editing any of javascript files. I rather suspect something is wrong with media and static settings.
And I can't click on javascript error message. I doesn't take me to any file.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Django 1.9.4 and django-filebrowser 3.6.4.

I checked Django 1.7 and django-filebrowser 3.5.8 and it works fine and same with Django 1.8 and django-filebrowser 3.6.4 and it works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working with Django 1.9 yet.